# How to Embed a full Node js App inside React Native to run on client's device

Tags: node.js, react-native, desktop-application, mobile-application

I'm a web dev with very little experience on mobile/desktop apps. I had an interesting idea that I would like to achieve even it ends up as a dead project in 2 months :) The thing is that I know very few on this non-web development processes or procedures so I need help.

I would like to achieve the following:

- A NodeJS app must run in client's device instead on a server.
- I would like to use React Native to ship windows, macOS, android and iOS apps

(I don't really know if I'll need one react native app for desktop and another one for mobile but I don't care at all at this point).

It probably needs to install Node inside the given device or include it on one way or another, then run node commands on the fly whenever it's needed such `node app.js`.

I've found [this lib](https://code.janeasystems.com/nodejs-mobile/) that can help with mobile devices -That I need to take a try and understand how it works- but I don't know if it would be the best workaround or which would be the best workaround for desktop windows/macOS as well.

Maybe require node through a setup? Embed a node installation inside?
Create a batch to run some native commands to mount the node server?

Make the user to download node before adding my application seems a bit weird to me.

I will appreciate any advice on how to proceed as well as any explanation to understand why to proceed like this.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the environment for the `Browser`, `Server`, and `RN` is a little bit different from each other alongside having consistent language (JavaScript).

If you wanna use a user's device as a server you should write your targets **cross-environment** by using JavaScript and then *serve* it by using [`react-native-static-server`](https://github.com/futurepress/react-native-static-server).

Just consider, the RN environment is a little different from the NodeJs environment.

Comment: The thing is I want to add a puppeteer inside that, as long as I can run Node in my computer I guess there's a way to provide this environment to launch a Node App inside client's device, will this solve this specific use-case? Can you provide any documentation about? thanks :)

Comment: @JoelBonetR, I did it before dear bro, but not like the things that you want, I added a RN server and ran a JavaScript app inside iOS, but all JavaScript codes were cross-env, I don't know level of your NodeJs application, but maybe if you transpile all codes to commonJs2, maybe, you could run it in iOS/Android app. About documentation really sorry, I don't have enough time. but follow the `react-native-static-server` docs, maybe it can help you.